# Can I create a gradle file with Kotlin to have all my dependencies?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, groovy

I'm migrating a multi-module project from Groovy to Kotlin Gradle on Android. Before I had several gradle files dedicated to different common things, for example I had in a gradle file those dependencies common to several modules of the project, then I only had to apply that file to the gradle files that I was interested in. Like this:

```
/**
 * Shared configuration between modules
 */

dependencies {

    // Kotlin dependencies

    implementation Dependencies.Kotlin.stdlibJdk7
    implementation Dependencies.Kotlin.coroutineCore

    // Dagger dependencies

    implementation Dependencies.Dagger.core
    kapt Dependencies.Dagger.coreCompiler

    // Logging dependencies

    implementation Dependencies.Logging.timber
    implementation Dependencies.Logging.slf4j
    implementation Dependencies.Logging.slf4jTimber


    // Shimmer dependencies

    implementation Dependencies.Shimmer.shimmer
}
```

When I convert this class to kotlin, I lose the access to implementation, is there any way to have a file like this or I have to do it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

The type-safe accessors aren't available in plain script plugins at the moment per [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#kotdsl:accessor_applicability).

There is a way to reproduce what you have in the Kotlin DSL though using precompiled script plugins, and re-applying the associated plugins to define the necessary dependency configurations. You could:

1. Create a [`buildSrc` folder](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources) (if you don't already have one) with a `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
// buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

2. Add the JARs that contain the plugins that define your target configurations (ie `implementation` and `kapt`) to the `implementation` configuration in `buildSrc`<sup>1</sup>:

```
// buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.22")
}
```

3. Write Kotlin [precompiled script plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins) within `buildSrc` with your dependencies, using plugins placed on the `buildSrc` classpath earlier:

```
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/dependencies.kts

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("kapt")
}

dependencies {
    implementation("group1:name1:version1")
    kapt("group2:name2:version2")
}
```

4. Include your script plugin where needed to add its containing dependencies

```
// subProject/build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    `dependencies` // id defined by the script plugin filename
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Putting plugin JARs on the `buildSrc` classpath like this will put the JARs on your buildscript classpaths throughout the project and, as a result, you have to remove any version declarations on those plugins in those buildscripts to avoid clashes, as required by Gradle